# Unexpected end of input on non-existing line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" on line 352, however I only have 349 lines of code. What does this mean? (The code is a bit messy my friend tried to do things but now it wont work. Also if you cant tell it's a discord music bot) (the "theres more code than text" error ON stackoverflow aggravates me)

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK9T8.png)

[error pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA0m8.png)

```js
function isYoutube(str) {
  console.log('function isYoutube is running')
  return str.toLowerCase().indexOf("youtube.com") > -1;
}
const Discord = require("discord.js");
//const client = new Discord.client();
const client = new Discord.Client(); //my better version hahahaahahhh
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const request = require("request");
const fs = require("fs");
const getYouTubeID = require("get-youtube-id");
const fetchVideoInfo = require("youtube-info");

var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./settings.json', 'utf-8'));

const yt_api_key = config.yt_api_key;
const bot_controller = config.bot_controller;
const prefix = config.prefix;
const discord_token = config.discord_token;

var queue = [];
//var isPlaying = false;
var dispatcher = null;
var voiceChannel = null;
var skipReq = 0;
var skippers = [];
//b
var musicServers = {}; //all servers playing music
var musicServer = {}; //current music server
var musicQueue = []; //queue in current server
var musicList = []; //names of music queue
var musicResults = []; //all results of search query
var musicSearch; //query for youtube search
var isPlaying = false; //is music playing
var isStreaming = false; //if music is streaming
var isSearch = true; //if query is for search
var isLooping = false; //if music is looping
var isSearching = false; //if searching

client.login(discord_token)

client.on('message', function(message) {
   if (message.author.equals(client.user)) return; //check if the client sent the message, if so ignore
   if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; //check for prefix
   var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" "); //take each argument
   console.log('function client.on is running')
   switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
    /*
    case "play":
      if (args[1].indexOf('youtube.com')) { //if it is a youtube link
        console.log('playing from link i think')
        voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
        isPlaying = true;
        voiceChannel.join().then(function (connection) {
          stream = ytdl(args[1], {
            filter: 'audioonly'
          });
          console.log(args[1])
          skipReq = 0;
          skippers = [];

          dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream);
        })
      }
      else { // if its a query
        //do shit
        for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
          var query = query + args[i] + " "
        }
        console.log(query)
      }
      break;
    case "pause":
      if (isPlaying == true) musicServer.dispatcher.paused = true, message.reply('paused')
      else message.reply('not playing anything b')
      break;
  }
  */
    case "play":
     isSearch = true;
     if (args[1]) { //if link or search query is provided, run code
      serverID = JSON.parse(message.guild.id);
      if (!message.member.voiceChannel) { //check if on voice channel
       message.reply('u not in voice channel b')
       return
      };
      if (isSearching == true) {
       message.reply('choose a song before you search again')
       return
      }
      if (args[1].indexOf('.com') && !args[1].indexOf('youtube.com')) {
       message.reply('only youtube b')
      }
      if (!musicServers[serverID]) musicServers[serverID] = {
       musicQueue: []
      };
      if (args[1].indexOf('youtube.com') >= 0) { //if its a link, run code
       musicServers[serverID].musicQueue.push(args[1]);
       musicServer = musicServers[serverID];
       info(message)
       isPlaying = true;
       isSearch = false;
      } else { //if its a search query, run code
       for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) { //for loop to loop through search query
        musicSearch = musicSearch + ' ' + args[i]
       }

        youtube.search(musicSearch, 5, function(error, result) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            //push results to public variable
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              //console.log(result.items[i])
              musicResults[i] = result.items[i]
            }
            //choose song out of results
            var ret = "\n\n`";
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              //console.log(musicResults[i].snippet)
              console.log(i)
              //console.log(ret += (i + 1) + ": " + musicResults[i].snippet.title + "\n")
              ret += (i + 1) + ": " + musicResults[i].snippet.title + "\n";
            }
            ret += "`"
            message.reply('search results:' + ret);
            isSearching = true;
            isSearch = true;
          }
        });
      }
      if (!message.guild.voiceConnection && isSearch == false) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection) {
        play(connection, message)
      });
      else if (isStreaming == false && isSearch == false) {
        play(connection, message)
      }
    } else {
      message.reply('pls provide a link or search query')
      return;
    }
    break;
  case "choose":
    serverID = JSON.parse(message.guild.id);
    args[1] = args[1] - 1;
    message.reply('now playing: ' + musicResults[args[1]].snippet.title)
    musicServers[serverID].musicQueue.push('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + musicResults[args[1]].id.videoId);
    console.log(musicServers[serverID].musicQueue[0])
    musicServer = musicServers[serverID];
    isPlaying = true;
    isSearching = false;
    info(message)
    if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection) {
      play(connection, message)
    });
    else if (isStreaming == false && message.guild.voiceConnection) {
      play(connection, message)
    }
    break;
  case "join":
    message.member.voiceChannel.join()
    message.reply('joining now!')
    break;
  case "skip":
    if (musicServer.musicQueue[0]) {
      serverID = JSON.parse(message.guild.id);
      musicServer = musicServers[serverID];
      musicList.shift()
      musicServer.dispatcher.end()
    }
    break;
  case "song":
    message.reply('currently playing ' + musicList[0].title + ' ' + duration)
    break;
  case "queue":
    var ret = "\n\n`";
    for (var i = 0; i < musicList.length; i++) {
      ret += (i + 1) + ": " + musicList[i].title + (i === 0 ? " **(current)**" : "") + "\n";
    }
    ret += "`"
    message.reply(ret);
    break;
  case "pause":
    if (isPlaying == true) musicServer.dispatcher.paused = true, message.reply('paused')
    else message.reply('not playing anything b')
    break;
  case "resume":
    if (isPlaying == true) musicServer.dispatcher.paused = false, message.reply('resumed')
    else message.reply('not playing anything b')
    break;
  case "loop":
    if (isLooping == true) {
      isLooping = false
    }
    if (isLooping == false) {
      isLooping = true
    }
    break;
    //moderation commmands
/* old shit
  if (mess.startsWith(prefix + "play")) {
    if (queue.length > 0 || isPlaying) { //add to queeueueueueu
      getID(args, function (id) {
        add_to_queue(id);
        fetchVideoInfo(id, function (err, videoInfo) {

          console.log('function fetchVideoInfo is running')

          if (err) throw new Error(err);
          message.reply(" added to queue: **" + videoInfo.title + "**");
        });
      });
    } else { //start playin and also joinininin
      console.log('start playing and joinin')
      isPlaying = true;
      getID(args, function (id) {
        queue.push(id);
        console.log('playing' + id)
        playMusic(id, message);
        fetchVideoInfo(id, function (err, videoInfo) {
          if (err) throw new Error(err);
          message.reply(" now playing: **" + videoInfo.title + "**");
        });
      });
    }

  }*/
  client.on('ready', function () {
    console.log("I am ready!");
  });
}
});


client.on('ready', function () {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});


function play(connection, message) {
  isStreaming = true;
  musicServer.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(musicServer.musicQueue[0], {
    filter: "audioonly"
  }));
  console.log('joined')
  info(connection, message)
  if (isLooping == false) musicServer.musicQueue.shift();
  musicServer.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
    if (musicServer.musicQueue[0]) musicList.shift(), message.reply('now playing ' + musicInfo.title.toLowerCase() + ' `' + duration + '` '), play(connection, message);
    else isPlaying = false, isStreaming = false, connection.disconnect();
  });
}

function info(message) {
  fetchVideoInfo(getYouTubeID(musicServer.musicQueue[0])).then(function(musicInfo) {
    musicList.push(musicInfo)
    if ((musicInfo.duration / 60) >= 1) { //if duration is more than a minute
      if ((musicInfo.duration / 3600) >= 1) { //if duration is more than a hour
        var hours = Math.floor(musicInfo.duration / 3600);
        if (Math.floor((musicInfo.duration / 60) - (hours * 3600)) < 0) {
          var minutes = 0
        } else {
          var minutes = Math.floor((musicInfo.duration / 60) - (hours * 3600));
        }
        var seconds = Math.floor((musicInfo.duration - (minutes * 60)) - (hours * 3600));
        if (minutes < 10) { //if less than 10 mins
          if (seconds < 10) { //if less than 10 secconds
            duration = `${hours}:0${minutes}:0${seconds}`
          } else {
            duration = `${hours}:0${minutes}:${seconds}`
          }
        } else { //if more than 10 mins
          if (seconds < 10) { //if less than 10 secconds
            duration = `${hours}:${minutes}:0${seconds}`
          } else {
            duration = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
          }
        }
      } else { //if duration is less than an hour, more than a minute
        if (Math.floor(musicInfo.duration / 60) < 10) { //if less than 10 minutes
          var minutes = Math.floor(musicInfo.duration / 60);
          var seconds = musicInfo.duration - minutes * 60;
          if (seconds < 10) { //if less than 10 secconds
            duration = `0${minutes}:0${seconds}`
          } else {
            duration = `0${minutes}:${seconds}`
          }
        } else {
          var minutes = Math.floor(musicInfo.duration / 60);
          var seconds = musicInfo.duration - minutes * 60;
          duration = `${minutes}:${seconds}`
        }
      }
    } else { //if duration is less than a minute
      if (musicInfo.duration < 10) { //if less than 10 secconds
        var seconds = musicInfo.duration;
        duration = `0${seconds}`
      } else {
        var seconds = musicInfo.duration;
        duration = `${seconds}`
      }
    }
    message.reply('added ' + musicInfo.title + ' `' + duration + '` to the queue')
  });
}


function playMusic (id, message) {
  console.log('function playMusic is running')
  voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;

  voiceChannel.join().then(function (connection) {
    stream = ytdl("https://youtube.com/watch?v=" + id, {
      filter: 'audioonly'
    });
    console.log("https://youtube.com/watch?v=" + id)
    skipReq = 0;
    skippers = [];

    dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream);
  });
}

function getID(str, cb) {
  console.log('function getID is running')
  if (isYoutube(str)) {
    cb(getYouTubeID(str));
  } else {
    search_video(str, function (id) {
      cb(id);
    });
  }
}

function add_to_queue(strID) {
  console.log('function add_to_queue is running')
  if (isYoutube(strID)) {
    queue.pish(getYouTubeID(strID));
  } else {
    queue.push(strID);
  }
}

function search_video(query, callback) {
  console.log('function search_video is running')
    request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&type=video&q=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&key=" + yt_api_key, function(error, response, body) {
        //console.log(body)
        //console.log(body.items[0])
    });

};
```

Comment: can u paste your `index.js` code to your question

Comment: Please post the code producing the error, we cannot help you debug without seeing what is happening.

Comment: The Syntax Error says it's unexpected end of input, that line should be the last one.

Comment: i added it @kgangadhar

Comment: The line `client.on('message', function(message) {`, where does that function end? You've got to tidy up your code, you'll have endless problems like this if you don't use indentation appropriately. I also highly recommend using an IDE that can tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you are just missing a closing curly and parenthesis in `line 229`?

So changing `};` to

```
    }
 });
```

Just before:
`client.on('ready', function () {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});`

It seems to me your forgot to close the callback function to `client.on('message'`, the changes above would fix that.

**Bonus:**
I would advise you to format your code "better".
It's up to you to wrap all `if` and `else` in curly braces, I think it improves code readability, but again, the choice is yours.
Semicolons also help when writing code, just like punctuation does in written text.

IDEs such as [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), [Sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) can really help you with keeping your code clean, and readable. Some even offer "auto formatting" which can be configured to your preferred coding style.

Comment: I did what you said however now i get a return binding error

Comment: Your new error is pointing out that it cannot find the `settings.json` file you are trying to open is missing. Please open up a new question regarding that issue if you cannot figure it out yourself. I believe this question has been answered.

Comment: @Turtle make sure you have `settings.json` in the same folder as the node.js file you are running so that `fs.readFile` can find it.

Comment: the settings.json is in the same folder as index.js. Is it looking for setting.json in a diffrent location? nvm its looking for it in the same folder idk why it cant find it

Comment: @Turtle you reference it like this `./settings.json`, then `./` means to look in the relative folder to the running file. If you are running `index.js` in the same folder as `settings.json` it shouldn't be a problem, make sure you have the right file permissions on the file and such and such. Again: **Make a new question with your new problem**, the original question has been answered and solved.